# why we can not create an instance of abstract class but we can with superclass?

Tags: oop, abstract-class, superclass

Why its allowed to create an object of superclass but not an abstract class. where in fact, if prevent creating an object of an abstract class then we should prevent creation of super class object.

Comment: A superclass is not necessarily abstract.

Comment: but in an abstract class you are allowed to add a constructor. so what is the point of that @Lennart

Comment: For example, to run some initialization that needs to be done for all derived classes. That way, you force your derived classes to call the ctor in the abstract class without having to repeat (or worse: forget) that initialization logic.

Comment: @Lennart okay I see when ever we call a function from an abstract class then it call's the constructor to initials.